# PHP encode a partial set of MySQL data into JSON

Tags: php, mysql, json

I know how to encode all the data from an SQL query into JSON using PHP, but don't know How to encode a partial set.

In Android (the client), I send an HTTP request which goes something like this:

```
public interface DataAPI {

       @GET("/top500")
        public void getResult(@Query("start") int start, @Query("count") int count,
                              Callback<Top500> response);
    }
```

As you can see, I am using start and count in Android code.
I have around 500 records in my table and I have successfully encoded all the data into JSON, using below PHP Script:

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB);

$sql = "select * from Persons";

$res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

$result = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
array_push($result,
array(
'id'=>$row[0],
'name'=>$row[1]    
));
}

echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

JSON Result:

```
{"result": [{ ... }]}
```

But I need to encode mysql data 20 by 20 like this:

```
{"count": 20, "start": 0, "total": 500, "result": [{ ...}]}
```

What's missing is how to use the *start* and *count* parameters to get a partial set in order to get slices of the data.

Comment: @RoyFalk thanks for editing it

Comment: yes .... @BhavikRathod

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code.

```
$con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB);

$count = "select count(*) as total from Person"; //query to get row count of your table
$count_res = mysqli_query($con,$count);
$count_row = mysqli_fetch_array($count_res);
$total = $count_row['total']; // get total no of records

$start = YOUR_START_VALUE; // from which offset you want to get record
$end = YOUR_VALUE // how many record want to fetch
$sql = "select * from Persons limit $start, $end";

$res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

$result = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
array_push($result,
array(
'id'=>$row[0],
'name'=>$row[1]    
));
}

echo json_encode(array("count"=> $end, "start"=> $start, "total"=> $total,"result"=>$result));

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` in your query. Applying some nasty logic in PHP is a bad solution. This is an operation that MySQL should do instead because you don't want to fetch all the rows if you don't need all of them.

If you run a query like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Persons
ORDER BY Id
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 20
```

you will get a subset of the matching rows starting from the 20th and long 10 rows. You can then loop over the full results set.

Better to explicitly order by a field to ensure consistency across different pages.

You're final code (using PDO rather than mysqli):

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:dbname=db;host=127.0.0.1', $user, $password);

$count = $_GET['count'];
$start = $_GET['start'];
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM Persons ORDER BY Id LIMIT ? OFFSET ?');
$stmt->execute(array($count, $start));
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    // your logic that was inside the while
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about something like:

```
$start = 7;
$size = 3;
$count = 0;

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
   if($count>=$start && $count <$start+$size) {
        array_push($result,array('id'=>$row[0],'name'=>$row[1]));
   }
   $count++;
}
```

The code should be self explanatory, but if you have any questions, feel free to comment.

*Note: This is more of a PHP pseudo code, as I don't have an environment and haven't coded in PHP in a while.*

Comment: yeah I agree with you, your code is self explanatory, but I am also not good in PHP, so really don't know how to get and use total, count and start, but still I would like to tick your answer as useful

Comment: This is not a good solution. You're fetching all the results from the DB and then you're reading just the slice that you need. It means that if you're DB has 100.000 rows and you want the last page you will loop over **all** of them. This should be offloaded to the DB, instead. As I explained below, `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` in MySQL serve exactly this purpose.

Comment: I agree with Alessandro. His solution is the way to go and I upvoted it accordingly. Note however, that with only 500 records, you can still go with my solution or even send it all in one go to the client and deal with it there. I am a firm believer in 'simplicity' over 'efficiency' if the latter isn't absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of 2 ways to solve this problem.

The first is using just MySQL:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM Persons LIMIT 0,20;

SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
```

With the first query you retrieve the batch of rows you want. With the second you get the total row count in the result set.

The second option is to use [array_slice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php):

```
$total = count($result);
$batch = array_slice($result, 0, 20);

echo json_encode(array("total" => $total, "start" => 0, "count" => count($batch), "result"=>$batch));
```